# Eclipse plugin to add "open the current folder in a file browser" feature

Tags: eclipse

Unlike Microsoft Visual Studio, Matlab or many other IDEs, Eclipse natively provides no way to easily open the current folder in Explorer. I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that can provide such feature. If possible, it should work for Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with Eclipse Kepler.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [StartExplorer](http://basti1302.github.io/startexplorer/):

- free Eclipse Plug-in
- Windows, Mac OS, Linux
- straightforward to install (just drag-and-drop the button to the Eclipse menu bar to install the plug-in)
- accessible via right click or keyboard shortcut
- add  “open the current folder in a file browser” feature as well as open a shell there and copy filepath in clipboard:

[image]